# Using .filter for sorting data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, vue.js

Basically what am I doing wrong? This is a chained filter under computed.

Error is 'product.topic.sort' is not a function.

I am trying to use 'select' to have a sort option of ascending, descending, price high & price low.

V-model binds value to the js.

Under filters I'm trying to add a filter that does this sorting based on 'value'

if value = undefined, do nothing. 
If value = Az, Ascending
if value = Za, Descending
if value = Ph, Price High
if value = Pl, Price low

**Edit**

Under `filteredSearch() {` I have other filters such as

```
  .filter(product => this.filters.some(filter => product.topic.match(filter))) || 
   this.products
  .filter(p => p.topic.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()))
  .filter(p => p.price <= this.priceFilter)
```

I want to ensure that all the other filters work with the sort filter.

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
            <h4>Sort</h4>  
                <select v-model="value">
                    <option value="Az">Ascending</option>
                    <option value="Za">Descending</option>
                    <option value="Ph">Price High</option>
                    <option value="Pl">Price Low</option>
                </select>



<div class="block" v-for="product in filteredSearch">
        <h3>{{product.topic}}</h3>
          <p>{{product.price}}</p>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                products: [{
                        "topic": "english",
                        "price": "20"
                    },
                    {
                        "topic": "french",
                        "price": "60"
                    },
                    {
                        "topic": "science",
                        "price": "80"
                    }
                ],
                value: "",
            })



computed: {

filteredSearch() {
return this.products
.filter((product) => {
    if (!this.value)
        return true;
    if (this.value == "Az") {
        return product.topic.sort(function(a, b) {
            a.topic - b.topic
        });
    }
})
}
}
});
```

Comment: You need to check `if (product.topic)`

Comment: How? Sorry I'm new to all of this.

Comment: What does product look like? Can we see the rest of the code? Can't really tell you what's wrong with just a snippet. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: provide the demo array which you are trying to filter

Comment: Have added the updates. Should be a lot clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [example](https://codepen.io/steve16351/pen/pooYGeW) of how to do this. So we have a helper method `getSorter` which looks at the currently selected value which your `v-model` directive is binding to `this.value`, and returns an appropriate function to pass to [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) based on that. If nothing is selected, it will return `null`.

In your computed property `filteredSearch`, you can apply your existing filters as you like, and then sort the outcome of that.

```js
methods: {
    // determine the sorting function to use
    getSorter() { 
      switch (this.value) {
        case 'Za':
          return (a,b) => b.topic > a.topic ? 1 : a.topic == b.topic ? 0 : -1;
        case 'Az':
          return (a,b) => b.topic > a.topic ? -1 : a.topic == b.topic ? 0 : 1;
        case 'Ph':
          return (a,b) => b.price - a.price;
        case 'Pl':
          return (a,b) => a.price - b.price;
        default:
          return null;
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredSearch: function() { 
      // apply existing filter logic
      var filteredProducts = this.products
        .filter((el) => true); // replace with your existing filter conditions here

      // apply sort function
      var sortFunction = this.getSorter();
      return sortFunction ? filteredProducts.sort(sortFunction) : filteredProducts;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I want though, I just don't know how to implement it.

Comment: In the code, you already return after filtering - change `return this.filters.length && this.products` to `var filteredProducts = this.filters.length && this.products`. And remove the line `.filter((el) => true);`, that was just an example line for filtering, it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't use filter in the computed property function, it's better to just do the sort like this

```js
filteredSearch() {
return !this.value ? 
        true 
        : this.value == "Az" ? 
        this.products.sort((a, b) => a.topic > b.topic ? 1 : -1)
        : this.value == "Za" ?
        this.products.sort((a, b) => a.topic < b.topic ? 1 : -1)
        : this.value == "Pl" ? 
        this.products.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price)
        : this.value == "Ph" ?
        this.products.sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price)
        : null;
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question slightly. I want all my other filters such as search etc, to work with my sort filter. If I do ^ only sort works and all the others don't.

Comment: The function was working with "Pl" and "Ph", I just corrected the first two cases. Please check now.